# Mapbox dependencies failed to resolve

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I had to adjust some packages in my Xcode project. Currently the entire project is broken and I am faced with this.

> Failed to resolve dependencies Dependencies could not be resolved because 'mapbox-maps-ios' depends on 'mapbox-common-ios' 24.2.0-beta.1 and 'mapbox-navigation-ios' depends on 'mapbox-navigation-native-ios' 182.0.0..<183.0.0. 'mapbox-navigation-native-ios' 182.0.0..<183.0.0 practically depends on 'mapbox-common-ios' 23.8.0..<24.0.0 because 'mapbox-navigation-native-ios' 182.0.0 depends on 'mapbox-common-ios' 23.8.0..<24.0.0 and no versions of 'mapbox-navigation-native-ios' match the requirement 182.0.1..<183.0.0.

Any help would be appreciated.